# Docker: Nginx + PHP-FPM -> index.php downloaded not shown

Tags: php, docker, nginx, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have created a simple project with Docker, Nginx, PHP-FPM and one index.php file in public folder. When I run a 'docker-compose up' command in PowerShell and go 'localhost' in my browser I get an error: index.php is downloaded and doesn't show phpinfo(). It seems that Nginx doesn't treat php-extension but I can't find an error.
Link to a github project:
https://github.com/pisarevaa/docker-nginx-php-fpm

Comment: What does `docker-compose logs` says ?

Comment: Unless I overlooked, there is no `fastcgi_pass` config param in your nginx configuration to link nginx to php-fpm. This question is not directly related to programming so is considered [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here. Try https://serverfault.com or https://superuser.com.

Comment: Thanks! It's partly healed the problem. It's also need to change www.conf in PHP-FPM by setting 'listen = 9000'. Please see final example: https://github.com/pisarevaa/docker-nginx-php-fpm